# Menu entry for Android x86 7.1 r2 installed alongside Ubuntu 16.04 does not work, system reboots when I test it

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, android

I've installed Android x86 7.1 r2, and now I'm trying to add the new OS to the boot menu.

I've run

```
gksu gedit /etc/grub.d/40_custom
```

And there I've added this code

```
menuentry "Android Ifti" {
set root='(hd0,5)'
linux /android-7.1-r2/kernel quiet root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.hardware=hp8670p acpi_sleep=s3_bios,s3_mode SRC=/android-7.1-r2 
initrd /android-7.1-r2/initrd.img}"
```

Then I ran the following commands

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/grub.d/40_custom
sudo update-grub
```

But when I select the option in the boot menu, some text appears which I can barely read as it's too fast, and the laptop restarts and the same boot menu reappears.

So the result is that nothing happens and the laptop restarts...
The quickly shown texts contain `Android x86 detected`.

I assume my menu entry code is incorrect. How can I fix it? I read [this Ubuntu Forums thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2307580) but it's for Android version 4.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

`androidboot.selinux=permissive`

to your kernel line.

If you dont, your system will reboot immediately

https://www.android-x86.org/source.html

> Note androidboot.selinux=permissive must be added since nougat-x86. Besides, before marshmallow-x86, androidboot.hardware= must be added to specify the target name of the built image. However, do not add this option since nougat-x86.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the same code.

I changed the code in my grub config for (Windows 10, Kubuntu and Androidx86 7.1-r2) and it works.

```
menuentry "Android-x86" {
set root='(hd0,5)'
linux /android-7.1-r2/kernel root=/dev/ram0 quiet androidboot.selinux=permissive
initrd /android-7.1-r2/initrd.img}
```

Resources:

- [Google groups - Crash back to grub after emergency remount](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-x86/ByRiRyX4-8E/NaRAMEslAgAJ)
- [MX Linux Forum](https://forum.mxlinux.org/viewtopic.php?t=43987)